# Asp Mvc Core 2 Identity not setting cookie name when using AddAuthentication().AddCookie()

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

Currently, and this works, I am doing the following to setup cookie authentication in an ASP MVC Core 2 app using  Identity:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieName";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
});
```

I want to add JWT to this app and according to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?tabs=aspnetcore2x), I do that by using something like this (based on the same configuration as above):

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOff";
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyCookieName";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{ // options });
```

When I do this (even if I leave off the `AddJwtBearer` chain) the cookie is no longer given the name I specify.  The login process still works and I get a cookie but it is named the default Asp cookie name.

I assume that these two methods of setting the options are the same and the `ConfigureApplicationCookie` is just a shortcut method to the same thing.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: You need to provide the authentication scheme name on your `AddAuthentication()`. Try `AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`?

Comment: Thanks David.  I did that and I get the same result, the cookie is named '.AspNetCore.Identity.Application' rather than 'MyCookieName'.

Comment: hmm weird, coz I had to specify the authentication scheme. If I leave it blank there, I got "No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found" error. From the cookie name you got '.AspNetCore.Identity.Application', are you using Identity Server 4?

Comment: I am using the regular asp core identity, not identity server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            // Jwt options.
        });

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
});
```

Comment: This compiles and I get the correct cookie name.  I have not fully tested whether I can connect using a token but I'll assume for now that I will be able to.  The docs made me think both auth methods needed to be chained after the AddAuthentication() call.  I'll report back after I get it all working in case anyone else comes across this.

Comment: @Brian: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Yes, I have this working.  It is setup the way the accepted answer is.   One other thing I had to do was to add the [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] attribute to the api controllers to force it to use the correct auth scheme.